# MongoDB: find document with largest amount of

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
"RecordId": 1, 
"CurrentState" : {
    "collection_method" : "Phone",
    "collection_method_convert" : 1,
    "any_amount_outside_of_min_max_fx_margin" : null,
    "amounts_and_rates" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef870670000000000000000"),
            "amount_from" : 1000.0,
            "time_collected_researcher_input" : null,
            "date_collected_researcher_input" : null,
            "timezone_researcher_input" : null,
            "datetime_collected_utc" : ISODate("2020-03-02T21:45:00.000Z"),
            "interbank_rate" : 0.58548,
            "ib_api_url" : null,
            "fx_rate" : 0.56796,
            "fx_margin" : 2.9924164787866,
            "amount_margin_approved" : true,
            "outside_of_min_max_fx_margin" : null,
            "amount_duplicated" : false,
            "fx_margin_delta_mom" : null,
            "fx_margin_reldiff_pct_mom" : null,
            "fx_margin_reldiff_gt15pct_mom" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5efdadae0000000000000000"),
            "amount_from" : 10000.0,
            "time_collected_researcher_input" : null,
            "date_collected_researcher_input" : null,
            "timezone_researcher_input" : null,
            "datetime_collected_utc" : ISODate("2020-03-02T21:45:00.000Z"),
            "interbank_rate" : 0.58548,
            "ib_api_url" : null,
            "fx_rate" : 0.57386,
            "fx_margin" : 1.9846963175514,
            "amount_margin_approved" : true,
            "outside_of_min_max_fx_margin" : null,
            "amount_duplicated" : false,
            "fx_margin_delta_mom" : null,
            "fx_margin_reldiff_pct_mom" : null,
            "fx_margin_reldiff_gt15pct_mom" : null
        }
```

Array of **amounts_and_rates** can contain different fields in different documents. Even inside one document.

I need to find the document with largest number of fields.
And also to find all possible fields in the **amounts_and_rates**. Collection can be rather large and check one by one can take rather long time. Is it possible to find what I need with aggregation functions of mongodb?

I want to have in the end something like:

```
[{RecordId: 1, number_of_fields: [13, 12, 14]}{RecordId:2, number_of_fields:[9, 12, 14]}]
```

Or even just max_records_number in `[{RecordId:2}, {RecordId: 4}]`.
Also would like to receive set of fields in **amount_and_rates** through the collection like:

```
set = ["_id", "amount_from", "time_collected_researcher_input" ...]
```

Comment: Yes, and this is only part of the document. In the amount_and_rates item can be any fields number.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of your 2 requirements,

#### The set of unique fields:

```
set = ["_id", "amount_from", "time_collected_researcher_input" ...]
```

- `$unwind` amounts_and_rates because its an array and need to use in `$project`
- `$project` converted object to array using `$objectToArray`
- `$unwind` again because amounts_and_rates is again an array and need to use in `$group`
- `$group` by null _id and add unique keys in set `amounts_and_rates` using `$addToSet`
- `$project` remove _id

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$CurrentState.amounts_and_rates"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      amounts_and_rates: {
        $objectToArray: "$CurrentState.amounts_and_rates"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$amounts_and_rates"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      amounts_and_rates: {
        $addToSet: "$amounts_and_rates.k"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6dPGM2hZ4vW

#### Fields count in sub document:

```
[{RecordId: 1, number_of_fields: [13, 12, 14]}{RecordId:2, number_of_fields:[9, 12, 14]}]
```

- `$unwind` amounts_and_rates because its an array and need to use in `$project`
- `$project` converted object to array using `$objectToArray` and get the count of particular document
- `$group` by `RecordId` and push all `arrayofkeyvalue` count in `number_of_fields` and added `total` for total count
- `$project` remove _id

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$CurrentState.amounts_and_rates"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      RecordId: 1,
      arrayofkeyvalue: {
        $size: {
          $objectToArray: "$CurrentState.amounts_and_rates"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$RecordId",
      RecordId: {
        $first: "$RecordId"
      },
      number_of_fields: {
        $push: {
          $sum: "$arrayofkeyvalue"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$arrayofkeyvalue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TRFsj11BqVR